# Wrapping a Callback Function

Tags: java, android, callback, android-volley

In an Android app that I'm writing, much of the app involves performing web requests to a specific API. Since the format of the data ends up being the same, I wanted to centralize many of the functions that I end up performing every request, rather than rewriting them every time.

For example, I perform the same error checking routine every time I make a web request:

```
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
boolean success = jo.getBoolean("success");
if(success) {
     //Do work
} else {
     //Display error
}
```

My thought was to make this some sort of class that implements `Response.Listener`, but I couldn't determine an effective way of handling errors and such. My question is *is there an easy way to perform repeated functions in callbacks?* I'm looking for an elegant solution, not necessarily the easiest.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by passing one or two interfaces to your method which is cumbersome. Java 8 brings you lambda which makes working with callback much more elegant. To use lambdas in Android you can use retrolambda: https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda

Your generic method could look like this

```
parseResponse(String response,
              Consumer<JSONObject> successConsumer, 
              Consumer<String> errorConsumer) {
   JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
   boolean success = jo.getBoolean("success");
   if(success) {
     successConsumer.accept(jo);
   } else {
     errorConsumer.accept("error");
   }
}
```

You would use this method like this:

```
class MyClass {
    void onResponse(String response) {
        ....
        parseResponse(response, this::handleData, this::handleError);
    }

    void handleData(JSONObject object) {....}
    void handleError(String object) {....}

}
```